# Get rows in dataframe if values are in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-visualization

I have two DataFrames (`df_users` and `df_managers`). Here is a sample of their data:

```py
df_users = pd.DataFrame({
   'name': ['Robert', 'Richard', 'Alex'],
   'branch': ['Chicago', 'Montreal', 'Paris'], 
   'name_tag': ['Robert#112', 'Richard#1069', 'Alex#5918']
})

df_managers = pd.DataFrame({
   'name': ['Robert', 'Richard', 'Alex', 'Rose', 'Abler'],
   'email': ['robert112@stack.com', 'richard1069@stack.com', 'alex5918@stack.com', 'rose4222@stack.com', 'abler6120@stack.com',
   'name_tag': ['Robert#112', 'Richard#1069', 'Alex#5918', 'Rose#4222', 'Abler#6120']
})
```

I want to filter `df_managers` with only the rows where `df_managers.name_tag == df_users.name_tag`. In other words, i need the rows in `df_managers` for Robert,  Richard and Alex.

What i tried (with no success):

```py
df_users_that_are_also_managers = df_managers[df_managers.name_tag.isin(df_users.name_tag)]

#or

[...] = pd.merge(df_managers, df_users, on=['name_tag'], how='left')
```

Note that `pd.merge()` also creates new columns in the merged dataframe depending on the existing columns. I need the exact same columns of `df_managers`.

Thanks

Comment: `pd.merge(df_managers, df_users['name_tag'], on=['name_tag'])`?

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
In [1792]: df_managers[df_managers.name_tag.isin(df_users.name_tag)]
Out[1792]: 
      name                  email      name_tag
0   Robert    robert112@stack.com    Robert#112
1  Richard  richard1069@stack.com  Richard#1069
2     Alex     alex5918@stack.com     Alex#5918
```

OR:

```
In [1793]: df_managers.merge(df_users['name_tag'])
Out[1793]: 
      name                  email      name_tag
0   Robert    robert112@stack.com    Robert#112
1  Richard  richard1069@stack.com  Richard#1069
2     Alex     alex5918@stack.com     Alex#5918
```

Comment: one question.. How are you answering two questions faster than i am copying the snippets to my workspace..?

Comment: @MattisSeehaus I'll take that as a compliment ;)

Comment: Indeed, you can. I just tried solving the other question you answered 2 mins ago. your speed is crazy. Have a good one.